# QSpinBox arrows place outside line edit (css)

Tags: css, qt, stylesheet, qspinbox

[image]
<sub>(source: [metrotek.spb.ru](http://wiki.metrotek.spb.ru/mw/images/a/a9/Style-override.png))</sub>

How to do it with Qt CSS help ?

I have try to use

```
subcontrol-origin: margin;
position: absolute;
```

but no success.

Thank for any help

**Edit**

Thank you for help and final CSS for my problem is:

```
QSpinBox#spin {
margin-left: 20px;  /* make room for the arrows */
margin-right: 20px;  /* make room for the arrows */
width: 20px;

border: 2 solid #515151;
background-color: #434343;
}

QSpinBox#spin::up-button  {
subcontrol-origin: margin;
subcontrol-position: center left;

width: 19px;
border-width: 1px;
}

QSpinBox#spin::up-arrow  {
image: url(:/res/images/up.png);

min-width: 19px;
min-height: 14px;
max-width: 19px;
max-height: 14px;
height: 19px;
width: 14px;
}

QSpinBox#spin::up-button:pressed  {
top: 1px;
right: 1px;
}

QSpinBox#spin::down-button  {
subcontrol-origin: margin;
subcontrol-position: center right;
width: 19px;
border-width: 1px;
}

QSpinBox#spin::down-arrow  {
image: url(:/res/images/down.png);

min-width: 19px;
min-height: 14px;
max-width: 19px;
max-height: 14px;
height: 19px;
width: 14px;
}

QSpinBox#spin::down-button:pressed  {
top: 1px;
left: 1px;
}
```

and additional CSS like a bonus :)
If you like to setup position for "up,down" arrows outside the edit at the right side only:

```
QSpinBox#spin {
margin-right: 40px;  /* make room for the arrows */
width: 20px;

border: 2 solid #515151;
background-color: #434343;
}

QSpinBox#spin::up-button  {
subcontrol-origin: margin;
subcontrol-position: center right;
position: relative;

left: -20px;   /*   shift position back*/
width: 19px;
border-width: 1px;
}

QSpinBox#spin::down-button  {
subcontrol-origin: margin;
subcontrol-position: center right;
width: 19px;
border-width: 1px;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you taken a look at the Qt Stylesheet guide? They have a really specific example of how to position your up and down arrows:

[here is the link](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qspinbox)

```
QSpinBox {
     padding-right: 15px; /* make room for the arrows */
     border-image: url(:/images/frame.png) 4;
     border-width: 3;
 }

 QSpinBox::up-button {
     subcontrol-origin: border;
     subcontrol-position: top right; /* position at the top right corner */

     width: 16px; /* 16 + 2*1px border-width = 15px padding + 3px parent border */
     border-image: url(:/images/spinup.png) 1;
     border-width: 1px;
 }

 QSpinBox::down-button {
     subcontrol-origin: border;
     subcontrol-position: bottom right; /* position at bottom right corner */

     width: 16px;
     border-image: url(:/images/spindown.png) 1;
     border-width: 1px;
     border-top-width: 0;
 }
```

Just adjust the subcontrol-position. And also adjust the padding for the QSpinBox to give it padding on the left as well.